# How to improve (time) resolution of touches locationInView

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, touches, touchesmoved

I am trying to program an iPhone app where the user can handwrite. I am using touchesmoved to track the user's finger, but I get between 30 and 50 updates a second. For quick finger movements, this is often no enough to get smooth letters: small letters like i often just get the touches began and then the touches ended points, with no points in between.

I was wondering if I could get better time (and space) resolution by using an NSTimer to query the touch object for its locationInView without waiting for it to call touchesmoved. Anyone knows if this might work?

Thanks.

Comment: You're right, it *might* work.

Comment: I guess you are right: I should just try. I just thought someone might have a better idea..

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise against NSTimer - its better to use CADisplayLink approach. For example, try to use my tiny lib https://github.com/nt9/NTLoop